# Why does string concatenation create extra parameters using Access and PYODBC?

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

[image: Example Query]

I created this procedure that I call with the cursor.execute method. The problem that I'm having is that PYODBC sees extra parameters than what I've given.
In this example query, the "*-" and "-*" are being read as extra parameters by PYODBC. Does anyone know why this is the case? This is happening any time I do any string concatenation in Access.

```
def GetAccessResults(self):

    with pyodbc.connect(SQL.DBPath) as con:
        cursor = con.cursor()

        if self.parameters == None:
            cursor.execute('{{Call {}}}'.format(self.storedProc))
        else:
            callString = self.__CreateStoredProcString()
            cursor.execute(callString, self.parameters)

        returnValue = cursor.fetchall()

    return returnValue

def __CreateStoredProcString(self):

    questionMarks = ('?,' * len(self.parameters))[:-1]

    return '{{Call {} ({})}}'.format(self.storedProc, questionMarks)
```

Comment: Since you building the sql on the fly, then you could dump the parameters statement. And if your column in question has spaces or other strange characters (bad), then surround the column name with [] (square brackets).

Comment: *PYODBC sees extra parameters than what I've given* ... please post actual error raised and code.

Comment: @Parfait I ran this exact same query without quotation mark portions and the query runs fine with the correct number of parameters. Once I add them back, no matter what's in the qutation marks, PYODBC adds two parameters. I updated my post with the code.

Comment: *PYODBC adds two parameters* ... once again, please post actual error/exception raised verbatim in body of question. Also, try using single quotes in stored Access query (double quotes are reserved for SQL identifiers). Access GUI does different things compared to Access ODBC.

Comment: @Parfait Sorry, I didn't think adding the exception would add any value to the problem here. You are correct though, and solved my problem. Once I switched to single quotes that query ran as expected. I just spent way too long trying to figure this out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Yeah I noticed this was the case. Is there any reason for the Parameters declaration up to for Access queries?

Comment: Actually, @RobertCriqui, are rows actually returning as expected despite no error? I have theory if not!

Comment: @Parfait Your comment about switching from " to ' proved to be the answer. Nothing was wrong with my python code, it was just the implementation in Access. Thanks again for your help. If you want to write up the answer I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Check use of `LIKE` [wildcard characters](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-wildcard-character-reference-af00c501-7972-40ee-8889-e18abaad12d1). By default, in ODBC, Access uses `%` and in GUI uses `*`. I just checked running Access pyODBC query in Python. But interestingly, this is NOT the case with stored queries!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As OP found out, MS Access being both a frontend GUI application and backend database operates differently in running SQL. Usually, the backend mode tends to be closer to standard SQL, namely:

- **Quotes**: In backend, single quotes are reserved for literals and double quotes for identifiers as opposed to being interchangeable inside MSAccess.exe.
- **Wildcards**: In backend, by default wildcards for `LIKE` uses `%` and GUI uses `*` unless running Access database in [SQL Server compatible syntax (ANSI 92)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-design-settings-for-objects-in-your-database-b6e0baa0-15d4-47ae-84c2-e0c46dcea23b) that uses the standard `%`. For this reason, consider Access' `ALIKE` (ANSI-Like) with `%` to be compatible in both Access modes. Interestingly, this is not the case with stored queries as OP uses but will if writing queries in code.
- **Parameter**: In backend, any unquoted object not recognized in query is considered a named parameter and errs out. Meanwhile the GUI launches a pop-up *Enter Parameter* box (which beginners do not know is actually a runtime error) allowing typed answers to then be evaluated on fly.
- **GUI Objects**: While in GUI, Access queries can reference controls in open forms and reports, even user-defined functions defined in standalone VBA modules, these same references will error out in backend which essentially runs Access in *headless* mode and only recognizes other tables and queries.
- **Optimization**: See Allen Browne's differences in [optimizations](http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html) that can occur when creating queries in GUI vs backend especially referencing Access object library functions.

---

By the way, using `LIKE` on subquery evaluates one scalar to another scalar. In fact, Access will err out if subquery returns more than one row which potentially can occur with current setup.

> Error 3354: At most one record can be returned by this subquery

In other databases, the evaluation runs on first row of subquery (which without `ORDER BY` can be a random row) and not all records of subquery. Instead, consider re-factoring SQL to use `EXISTS` clause:

```sql
PARAMETERS prmServiceName Tex(255);
SELECT c.* 
FROM Charts c
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 
   FROM Services s
   WHERE s.ServiceName = prmService_Name
     AND c.FileName ALIKE '%-' & s.Service_Abbreviation & '-%');
```

Comment: This is amazing and I got way more than I bargained for. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using ampersands:

```
Select "*-" & Service_Abbreviation & "-*"
```

Also, **Like** expects a string wrapped in quotes, and your subquery doesn't return that. So perhaps:

```
Select "'*-" & Service_Abbreviation & "-*'"
```

Comment: I tried it originally like that and it didn't work.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Please post Python errors/exceptions and code. It may be due to your implementation.

Comment: Added quotes to the returned value.

Comment: This doesn't work either. The query I posted works fine when run inside Access, just trying to query it with PYODBC causes the files because of the extra parameters. When I add the ' the query fails to return any results inside Access.